# Google analytics current pageview URL overwritten by events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application

Does anyone know the solution to maintaining the correct active page URL when sending events from an SPA using pushstate? Here's the scenario:

User arrives at /home (page title is 'Home') and ga is inited:

`ga('send', 'pageview');`

User moves to /my-account (page title is 'My Account'):

`ga('send', 'pageview', '/my-account');`

Use plays an audio track:

`ga('send', 'event', 'player', 'play', 'radio');`

In google realtime content we now see an active user in /home (page title 'My Account')

It seems that the event reverts the page URL to the entry page URL, not the currently viewed page, even though the browser history reflects the new page. If a new pageview is sent the correct URL is listed in the realtime listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're only [sending](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits) the new page path in the hit instead of [setting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers) it on the tracker objects (which would then apply it to all subsequent hits).

This is a common problem with single page applications (which it sounds like you're making). Check out the [single page applications guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) for analytics.js to get a better understanding of how to do this properly.

As an alternate option, you can use the new [autotrack plugin](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack), which will track URL changes automatically and takes care of updating the tracker object for you.

Comment: Ah thank you yes. So for the record this is what we should be doing:

`ga('set', 'page', '/my-account')`
`ga('set', 'title', 'My Account')`
`ga('send', 'pageview')`

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also do the setting in one line if you prefer: `ga('set', {page: '/my-account', title: 'My Account'})`.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well, I set `nonInteraction` property to true and it works.

```
ga("send", "event", {eventCategory: "category", eventAction: "action", eventLabel: "label", eventValue: "value", nonInteraction: true})
```

**Non-Interaction Events**

The term "Non-interaction" applies to the final, and optional, the boolean parameter that can be passed to the method that sends the Event hit. This parameter allows you to determine how you want bounce rate defined for pages on your site that also include event measurement. For example, suppose you have a home page with a video embedded on it. It's quite natural that you will want to know the bounce rate for your home page, but how do you want to define that? Do you consider visitor interaction with the home page video an important engagement signal? If so, you would want interaction with the video to be included in the bounce rate calculation, so that sessions including only your home page with clicks on the video are not calculated as bounces. On the other hand, you might prefer a more strict calculation of bounce rate for your home page, in which you want to know the percentage of sessions including only your home page regardless of clicks on the video. In this case, you would want to exclude any interaction with the video from bounce rate calculation.

That's where the optional non-interaction parameter steps in. Remember that a bounce is defined as a session containing only one interaction hit. By default, the event hit is considered an interaction hit, which means that it is included in bounce rate calculations. However, when this value is set to true, the type of event hit is not considered an interaction hit. You can use this fact to adjust bounce rate calculations for pages that contain events. Setting this value to true means: a session containing a single page tagged with non-interaction events is counted as a bounce—even if the visitor also triggers the event during the session. Conversely, omitting this option means that a single-page session on a page that includes event measurement will not be counted as a bounce if the visitor also triggers the event during the same session.

[More detail about nonInteraction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068#NonInteractionEvents)